# multiprocessing of reading a lot of file and working with those file in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to read almost 50 files that have large sizes so is it possible to divide a few files per processor (let's say 5 files per possessor if I take 10 processor)?
I am at a very beginner stage in multiprocessing in python. I am trying the below code but I think the problem is here it is reading the file sequentially (after completing reading one file another is started to read). My code is in below

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import pandas as pd
import glob

def process(fileread):
    print(multiprocessing.current_process())
    return pd.read_csv(fileread,header=None,sep='\s\s+|,',engine='python')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)

    for i sorted(glob.glob("*.dat")):
         result = pool.map(process,[i])
         print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I am getting print here sequentially one after another file. I think I could not do the right code may be. looking for help.

For your information,  files can be read randomly i.e. no need to read in a particular way.

Comment: It looks like you are calling `pool.map()` only for a single file. The function will block until all elements are mapped. Since you pass only a single file, it will block for each file. Try passing all files at once: `result = pool.map(process, sorted(glob.glob("*.dat")))` (and remove the `for` loop). After this the file contents should be in `result`.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielJunglas for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @avi, the way you had previously written it, you could have used `apply_async` instead of `map`, however using `map` properly as Daniel described is likely a better solution.